# Arabic chapter numbers in ToC, Words in chapter headings in ConTeXt

Tags: table-of-contents, sectioning, context, chapters

My first post on tex.sx, so bear with me...

**The Goal**: Arabic chapter numbers in the Table of Contents, and Words in the chapter headings (i.e. Chapter One)

Seems simple enough, but I'm having the darnedest time getting it right. If I use this...

```
\definestructureconversionset
 [words]
 [Romannumerals, Words, numbers, numbers, numbers]
 [numbers]

\setuphead 
 [chapter]
 [page=chapterpagebreak,
  sectionconversionset=words,
  header=empty,
  footer=empty,
  numberstyle={\scx},
  textstyle={\bfd},
  align={middle, nothyphenated, verytolerant},
  command=\MyChapter
 ]
```

... then I end up with a Table of Contents like this:

One     Chapter Title
Two     Chapter Title

I've scoured here, the wiki, manuals, and I still haven't found a solution, so any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Anybody anybody? @marco, the ConTeXt master?! Haha

Answer (score 1):

A bit late to the party, sorry.

You can use `deepnumbercommand` together with `\convertnumber`.  The `deepnumbercommand` option takes a command with one argument and `\convertnumber` takes two arguments, where the first one is the conversion set and the second one is the number.  What we can do is, we can [curry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Currying) the `\convertnumber` macro by giving it only one argument, technically making it a macro that takes one argument.

```
deepnumbercommand=\convertnumber{words}
```

Here is the full example.

```
\definestructureconversionset
  [words]
  [Romannumerals, Words, numbers, numbers, numbers]
  [numbers]

\setuphead 
  [chapter]
  [page=chapterpagebreak,
   header=empty,
   footer=empty,
   numberstyle={\scx},
   textstyle={\bfd},
   align={middle, nothyphenated, verytolerant},
   deepnumbercommand=\convertnumber{words}]

\starttext

\completecontent

\startchapter[title={Title 1}]

\stopchapter

\startchapter[title={Title 2}]

\stopchapter

\stoptext
```

[image]